# ¿Por qué recibo el mensaje "Unresolved reference 'base'" al crear un objeto?

Tags: python, poo

Estoy intentando crear una clase que tenga la base y la altura de un triángulo y me devuelva el área.

Sin embargo cuando intengo darle al print me dice:

```
Unresolved reference 'base'
Unresolved reference 'altura'
```

¿En qué me estoy equivocando?

```
class Rectangulo:
    base ='4'
    altura='2'

    def Resultado(self,base,altura):
        area=((base*altura)/2)
        return f'{area}'


    mi_cadena = Rectangulo()
    print(mi_cadena.Resultado())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las variables `base` y `altura`, tal cual están definidas

```
class Rectangulo:
    base ='4'
    altura='2'
```

son variables de **clase**, no de **instancia**.

Las variables de clase están asociadas a la clase en su conjunto, no a un objeto en particular (una instancia de la clase). Para usarlas hay que anteponerles el nombre de la clase, como en esta función de prueba:

```
class Rectangulo:
    base ='4'
    altura='2'

    def test_variables(self):
         print(f"base = {Rectangulo.base}")
         print(f"altura = {Rectangulo.altura}")
```

La función `Resultado` tiene `base` y `altura` por parámetros, que aunque se llaman igual, no tienen relación con las variables de clase `base` y `altura`. Además, son parámetros obligatorios, y tienes que proporcionarlos al llamar a la función.

**Versión corregida**

```
class Rectangulo:
    base ='4'
    altura='2'

    def Resultado(self,base,altura):
        area=((base*altura)/2)
        return f'{area}'

    def test_variables(self):
        print(f"base = {Rectangulo.base}")
        print(f"altura = {Rectangulo.altura}")
```

prueba:

```
mi_cadena = Rectangulo()
mi_cadena.test_variables()
print(mi_cadena.Resultado(5, 6))
```

produce:

```
base = 4
altura = 2
15.0
```

**Forma correcta**

La clase `Rectangulo` está mal modelada. Un rectángulo está definido por su base y altura, y cada instancia debería recibir ambos parámetros en el método `__init__`, mientras que la función `area` retornara el área de dicho rectángulo:

```
class Rectangulo:

    def __init__(self, base, altura):
        self.base = base
        self.altura = altura

    def area(self):
        return (self.base * self.altura) / 2
```

Prueba:

```
mi_cadena = Rectangulo(5, 6)
print(mi_cadena.area())
```

produce:

```
15.0
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias por la explicación. Si lo he entendido bien, hay que construir la función con __init__ para que los parámetros de base y altura los pueda coger las funciones siguientes. Lo que no entiendo es el self de deltante de base y altura, ¿por qué se pone si previamente se escribió self en el paréntesis? Gracias de antemano

Comment: `self` es la instancia. `self.base` significa "La variable `base` propia de esta instancia (`self`)". La `base` en el paréntesis es el nombre con que accedes al valor pasado por el llamante. Es el mismo nombre, pero son dos variables distintas.