# Python: error al crear una clase que me pida dos números

Tags: python

Soy nuevo en el mundo de python y me he encontrado ante un error básico pero que no se resolverlo por mi falta de experiencia en este lenguaje.

Intento recoger dos números que el programa me pide. Este programa lo he metido dentro de una clase, sin embargo me da este error

```
   Unresolved reference 'notas'
```

a la hora de mostrar por pantalla los dos números.

```
 class Validator:
     notas = []
     def __init__(self):
         for i in range(0, 2):
             self.notas.append(float(input('Dame nota:')))
 
     def set_notas(self, notas):
         self.nota = notas
         return notas

 listado_notas=Validator()
 print(listado_notas.set_notas(notas))
```

El error que da muestra que no he definido notas, pero previamente mencioné notas=[] ¿no es suficiente con esto? ¿Dónde debo de cambiarlo?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: En la última línea, `notas` no está definida. En ninguna parte hay un lista de notas con que inicializar nada.

Comment: ¿Cómo la defino? Creía que con poner notas=[ ] al principio era suficiente para definirlo. Por estas cosas estoy preguntándolo por aquí, porque creía que este es un sitio para preguntar y aprender no de reprender

Comment: toma un rato para leer la respuesta que te dio @CandidMoe en [¿Por qué recibo el mensaje “Unresolved reference 'base'” al crear un objeto?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/407432/83). Una vez interiorizado, revisa tu código. Si te resolvemos cada paso, no vas a aprender.

Comment: *previamente mencioné notas=[]*, la cual es una variable interna de la Clase, y no tiene ámbito o alcance global. En todo caso, el método `set_notas()` espera recibir una lista externa a la Clase, a partir de  la cual establecer el valor interno. Saludos

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
class Validator:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.notas = []  #inicializar la lista dentro del init y con self para el alcance global
        for i in range(0, 2):
            self.notas.append(float(input('Dame nota:')))

    def set_notas(self):  #no es necesario pasar por parámetro
        self.nota = self.notas #no hay que olvidar en este caso el self
        return self.nota #no se porque pero vas a devolver nota(sino para que la declarás), no notas

listado_notas=Validator()
print(listado_notas.set_notas())#llamás el método sin parámetro.
```

Comment: Escribir sólo código como respuesta es considerado de baja calidad. Por favor leer [answer]. El comentario en el código no basta para dar una explicación clara y concisa del error que comete el OP. Saludos

Comment: @tincopasan, muchas gracias por el código, funciona genial, voy a analizarlo detenidamente las anotaciones que me has hecho. Entiendo que quizás para vosotros parece una tomadura de pelo que os pregunte por cada cosa que no entiendo pero por eso lo hago para entenderlo y dejar de molestar con errores de novato. Disculpad

Comment: @MauricioContreras la explicación clara y concisa del error está explicada dentro de la respuesta dada. No obstante tu comentario también me ha servido para detectar mi error. Gracias

Comment: @AdriánP.L. no a todos nos molestan las preguntas, para mí lo más importante es que intentaste algo, lo que molesta es que piden y no hacen ni una línea de código. Son como los que votan negativo, y funciona, se creen puristas del código y la pagina.